# Imap-get the attachment maximum size limit

Tags: php, imap

Is there any functon which shows attachment size limit for a mail services such as Gmail, Yahoo etc using php-imap ?

Normally it's **25 MB** for yahoo and mail and **10 MB** for hotmail.
But I need a function to find that, so that i can use as a service

Comment: For sending, see the SMTP SIZE extension, RFC 1870.  For IMAP, some servers use the APPENDLIMIT extension, but it's generally unnecessary as it will be at least as high as SMTP SIZE.

Comment: Ok Thanks Max. How can I able to change the size limit ?

Comment: That's a server configuration option.  You'll need to look up the documentation for whatever server you use, if you control it.

Comment: Ok.How do I know that the maximum size of attachment is around 25 MB, i mean using any php function ? I don't have much idea

Comment: If you're trying to send email, look at your smtp library to see if it gives you access to the EHLO response, which may have a SIZE= parameter.  If it doesn't, you'll have to guess.